# concatening rows in a rails style

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Suppose I want to check if some `string` appears as `name`-`surname` in the concatenation of two rows `name` and `surname` of a `table`. How do I write valid this sql in a rails style ? And is these syntaxes correct ?

```
SELECT (name + '-'+ surname) FROM table1 where (name + '-'+ surname = string)


table.select(:name+'-'+:surname).where((:name+'-'+:surname) == string)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood but maybe this is will do the job: `YouModel.select('(name+"-"+surname) AS computed_name').where('computed_name = ?', 'my-string-to-test')`

Comment: ok this is exactly what I a m looking for, could you put it as an answer so i can validate it !

Comment: I jsut posted an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I am understanding your question correctly, but I think this is what you are wanting. For the following string variable,

```
string = "John - Doe"
```

you want to pull a record like this from the User table

id   | name    | sur_name

1    | John    | Doe

If this is what you want, you can actually massage your string variable like this

```
parsed_string = string.split('-')
name = parsed_string[0].strip # strip to remove white spaces
sur_name = parse_string[1].strip
```

Then, you can run the following code to get what you want:

```
users = User.where(:name => name, :surname => sur_name)
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: By the way, this is not really a Rails question. But, I answered in Rails way. :)

Comment: this is it, but I wanted to have one single sql query without dealing with splitting the string. Thanks anyway

Comment: I am not sure the size of your table, but putting computation on the db during a query call can get very expensive. If the query does a full table scan, and it has to compute (e.g. concatenating two column values), it will be troublesome even for the greatest RBMS.